# How can I tweak the amount of RAM allocated to Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, ram

I have a Samsung S4 running Android version 4.4.2. I am using Chrome browser version 35.0.1916.141. I am constantly on the go and I utilize my phone's browser pretty heavily. I've noticed that with heavy use, it becomes sluggish. This is very frustrating when I  am trying swift through my open tabs while maintaining a fluid experience.

My question was `How can I tweak the amount of RAM allocated to Chrome for Android?`

Answer (score 1):

I found a tweak that will allow me to manipulate the amount of RAM that is allocated to the Chrome browser on Android.

By default the Chrome browser for Android can only access up to 128MB of RAM. This can be tweaked by simply opening the application `Chrome Browser` and typing the following string in a new tab and tap *Enter*:

> chrome://flags/#max-tiles-for-interest-area

In the menu that pops up, change the value from `Default` to `256` or `512`.

You will be prompted with a notification that will ask you to *Relaunch Google Chrome* in order for your changes to take effect. Click `Relaunch Google Chrome` and enjoy the added speed.